# Error in SQLAlchemy with Integer: "object() takes no parameters"

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I suddenly started seeing an error in my Python SQLAlchemy application and I can't figure out what's causing it. My code looks like this:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import Column
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy import Integer
from sqlalchemy import MetaData
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

def loadConnection(connection_string, echo=False):
    engine = create_engine(connection_string, echo=echo)
    Base = declarative_base(engine)
    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    session = Session()
    return session, Base

connection = yaml.load('connection.yaml')
session, Base = loadConnection(connection['connection'], connection['echo'])

class Foo(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'foo'
    id = Column(Integer(11), primary_key=True)
```

And when I run this script I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ephem/database_interface.py", line 52, in <module>
    class Foo(Base):
  File "ephem/database_interface.py", line 54, in Foo
    id = Column(Integer(11), primary_key=True)
TypeError: object() takes no parameters
```

I am using SQLAlchemy 0.9.1. My backend is MySQL running on the localhost. As far as I can tell by inspecting with pdb `connection`, `session`, `Base`, `Column`, and `Integer` all seem normal.

Comment: According to [docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/types.html#sqlalchemy.types.Integer), `Integer` takes no arguments.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Integer` takes no parameters. This is a change in version 0.9.

There exist `BigInteger` and `SmallInteger` instead.

Comment: Note that it took arguments in 0.8 version: [docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/types.html#sqlalchemy.types.Integer).

Comment: ^^^ @alecxe AH-HA! I had to rebuild my python environment this week. I bet that upgraded me from 0.8 to 0.9 without me noticing!

Comment: @ACV, yeah, that's why it's better to freeze project requirements with precise package versions - who knows what is going to change in your dependencies.